# How can I create a view from two tables to make a report in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have two tables `patient_data` and `patient_test`.

`patient_data`:

```
lab_no      p_name
1              p1
2              p2
3              p3
4              p4
```

`patient_test`:

```
lab_no         test_name
1                 t1
1                 t2
1                 t3
2                 t1
2                 t2
3                 t2
4                 t1
4                 t3
```

When I try this code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "create view reg as SELECT patient_data.lab_no,patient_data.p_name,patient_test.test_name,patient_test.price from patient_data INNER JOIN patient_test on patient_data.lab_no = patient_test.lab_no where patient_data.lab_no ='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
```

It returns an error and I don't know what the problem is.
Can you help me in this?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the error that it returns?

Comment: "type mismatch in expressien"      this massage apper when i tried to open query from database

Comment: If `lab_no` is an integer, you shouldn't put single quotes around it: `... where patient_data.lab_no = " & TextBox2.Text`

Comment: i delete single quotes and it is the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to create a view? cmd.CommandText = "SELECT patient_data.lab_no,patient_data.p_name,patient_test.test_name,patient_test.price from patient_data INNER JOIN patient_test on patient_data.lab_no = patient_test.lab_no where patient_data.lab_no =" & TextBox2.Text

Comment: ok it is solved lab_no in patient_data wasn't integer     thank you very much for help